# Should I say "the park sitting area" or "the park's sitting area"?

Tags: grammar

I always get confused with constructions like that.

Example sentence:

> Before I knew, it found myself at Chou Park. More exactly at the park
>   resting area.

Comment: Why **resting area** when it should be **rest area**? And you don't need possessive here, just **"at the park rest area"**.

Comment: **The rest area of the park = The park's rest area.** However, if the earlier part of the sentence specified that you were in the park, you can just say **; more specifically at the rest area.**

Comment: Native speaking would always refer to *the park **seating** area*, not ***sitting** area*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either.

> The park sitting area.

An attributive noun modifier (the **park** sitting area) can be understood to mean something like the possessive, i.e. the sitting area *of the park*.

"The park sitting area" has the underlying meaning "the sitting area that is *typical* of parks."  It refers to the sitting area as an attribute of class "Park", of which this one park is a typical instance.

Much the same idea can be expressed with the possessive:

> The park's sitting area.

This park's particular sitting area.

When something is universal, we tend to use the attributive over the possessive:

**the door jamb** rather than **the door's jamb**

although using the possessive is fine, especially if you want to refer to something *atypical* about this door's jamb.

Attributive noun modifiers don't always have that meaning, however. Chicken soup is not the chicken's soup, but soup made of chicken.